# How to create root stage with multiple scene in Java FXML

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create root stage which have login page after login it page redirect on Main Application. After that, Menu bar which will be fix and AnchorPane will be change according to Menu-Items. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As a tool for drag & drop user interface design in JavaFX I can recommend you [Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/). For you particular task of creating a login page have a look at the official example **FXML Login Demo**:

[image]

To launch the demo:

1. Download [Java Demos and Samples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
2. Extract archive
3. Launch extracted-folder/demo/javafx_samples/Ensemble8.jar

```
$ java -jar Ensemble8.jar
```

4. In the search field type *FXML Login Demo*